# MS-Build returning the visual studio installation path

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, mstest

How can the entry

```
<MsTestExePath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe</MsTestExePath>
```

in a .proj file be generalised, such that the build works for different licenses of Visual Studio 2019 as well, where mstest.exe is located at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe

in the case of an enterprise license?

The most generic solution may be to replace the variable parts of the path with msbuild macros, but which ones would that be?

Comment: Does `<MsTestExePath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\....` work? Looks like the backslash is no need to add.(Refer to this document: [MSBuild reserved and well-known properties – MSBuildProgramFiles32 – Do not include the final backslash on this property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2015#:~:text=msbuildprogramfiles32)) Perhaps you can have a try.

Comment: You are right, I corrected it in the original answer. And thanks for pointing me to the right  direction: According to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-160

$(VSInstallDir)  seems to be the property I am looking for.

Comment: Good to know that the `$(VSInstallDir)` is the key.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-160),

The macro

```
$(VSInstallDir)
```

returns the path to the installation folder of the Visual Studio version currently used.

The following entry should therefore work for all versions of visual studio, for which mstest.exe is located in the subfolder \Common7\IDE\ under the installation directory:

```
<MsTestExePath>$(VSInstallDir)Common7\IDE\mstest.exe</MsTestExePath>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the MsBuild bin directory and found the following:
$(DevEnvDir)..\..\Msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.dll